# IE bug responsive

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, windows-phone, internet-explorer-10

I've a problem with my responsive design in IE (mobile resolution).

I've just been busy with a correct view in Android and iOS phones. But now I've recognized that the mobile view for IE (10) on windows mobile (8) bugs.

The problem is that on the right side of the website there's a blank space.

I suspect it's not a problem with the viewport. Most responsive websites are working just well on windows mobile. I've tried some different viewports, also from working websites, but that doesn't fix the problem.

Probably there's another bug in the HTML or CSS that make the browser think there's more content. Maybe an overflow or something? I tried to set the overflow-x: hidden and overflow-y: scroll, that works for IE on my computer (in mobile size), but not on the windows phone

I hope somebody could help me with finding out this problem.

Comment: Same here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14536211/wp8-ie10-viewport-issue

Comment: Just tested on IE10 and WP8 emulator and I don't see the "on the right side of the website there's a blank space." problem mentioned.

Comment: Closed because the question is too specific? Wow, some people just don't like questions on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't recreate your issue. Is this issue still relevant?
Usually (in my experience) such white side stripes were caused by some not properly wrapped block elements and floats that span/shift the viewport. For more specific answer would be cool to see the actual issue.

P.S.
Not the best answer, though since I've jumped on bootstrap bandwagon I forgot about such headaches :)
Best luck
A.