# WP8 IE10 viewport issue

Tags: css, windows-phone-8, viewport, internet-explorer-10

Did any of you noticed that when using -ms-viewport (with specific width of 320px or device-width) then web browser content can be moved outside available space? It seems like document size is wrong so i can scroll it's content to the left but there is nothing then white empty space. I can also zoom it out(but i should not) and it's size after that is not always the same. I'm aware of http://mattstow.com/responsive-design-in-ie10-on-windows-phone-8.html but it does not help. It happens after second or third navigate to the same content and disappears for example when device is rotated.

Answer (score 3):

Windows Phone 8 does not properly recognize the `meta viewport` tag that is standard for webkit and mobile web.

Try this in your CSS

```
@-ms-viewport{width:device-width}
```

And then add this JS

```
if (navigator.userAgent.match(/IEMobile\/10\.0/)) {
    var msViewportStyle = document.createElement("style");
    msViewportStyle.appendChild(
        document.createTextNode(
            "@-ms-viewport{width:auto!important}"
        )
    );
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].
        appendChild(msViewportStyle);
}
```

[More here (credit)](http://timkadlec.com/2013/01/windows-phone-8-and-device-width/)

Comment: Sorry, I realize this is similar to the source you already cited, I'll leave it up for posterity.

Answer (score 0):

try adding the following

```
@-ms-viewport {
    user-zoom: fixed;
    max-zoom: 1;
    min-zoom: 1;
}
```

Comment: The problem is that i cant restrict zoom usage. And it still does not work. I noticed that someone here is facing the same problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743992/ie-bug-responsive

Comment: I think it can be doctype related. When I removed the doctype then the page looks ugly but there is no problem anymore.

Comment: I can't repro the similar problem (see my comment in related issue). Please post your sample page on jsFiddle

Comment: It's really complex problem and i think it's a race condition. There is a div in page content with img inside that src is defined as inline data base64 gif. I'am also using XHTML 1.0 Strict doctype and when it's removed so it's in quirks mode the issue is gone. So i think that when using viewport combined with xhtml and img uri data then browser engine calculates page dimensions wrong. I also tried to specify height and width of div and img tag but it does not work either. The only thing that works is to inject img content in onload event of the page.